# JavaScript serviceIsBusy error OnSave of CRM form?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, xrm

CRM 365 OnPremise.

I have an `Accounts.js` that contains the following code simplified for the example:

```
Xrm.Page.data.save().then(
    function() {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Record saved");
     },
    function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    });
```

The idea is that the form saves, then when the async save is complete it triggers the alert dialog to say 'record saved'.

The problem is that the error function is being triggered, but the error is simply 'serviceIsBusy'.

Can anyone explain how to get around this or what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the official way does not work for OnPremise CRM 365.  I have absolutely no idea why and even less time to troubleshoot.

The solution i found somewhere on stack overflow was this 'old' way:

```
   //trigger form save and wait 1 sec
    Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
    setTimeout(function () {
        saveAccountOK(context);
    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually `Xrm.Page.data.save()` is to invoke the same save button action from the entity form, but if you call this method from the form save event itself then it will endup in loop.

Since you want to make use of `.then()` handler for custom need, you can prevent the default `save` operation and invoke the manual `save` as you do.

You can understand form [this community thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/248967/javascript-error-server-is-busy).

```
function onSave(context){
    context.getEventArgs().preventDefault();

    Xrm.Page.data.save().then(
      function() {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Record saved");
     },
      function(error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  When i saw that i jumped for joy as it does look like the solution.  Sadly the serviceIsBusy is still returned.

context is correctly passed in but it still generates the error.

I am currently reading through your link which suggests using a timer to wait out the save, something i have already tried and it works.  But i was hoping to get this working as it is supposedly the recommended way?

thanks again.

Comment: @DaveC so it’s working only with settimeout.. it’s weird

Comment: yes, i have also stripped all other java from the form and commented out the guts of the plugin.  Still the same result.  Its a working soln using the timer but i don't like the the fact the delay is fixed :/  I would love to accept your answer Arun but unfortunately even though it seems correct it just wont work for me.

Comment: @DaveC I agree, this is not perfect solution. Given the requirement, without any official documentation I would take the community identified supported workaround.